# how to have multiple cards in each Carousel slide react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm working with react-bootstrap and I have my data coming from an API and saved in `recipes` as an array.

I'm trying to have Carousel with react-bootstrap but right now it shows each item on a separate slide, how can I show 3 items on each slide?

this is my code

```
<div>
      <Wrapper>
      <h3>Breakfast Recipes</h3>
      <Carousel>
        {recipes.map((item,index) => (       
          <Carousel.Item key={index}>
                <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.photo_location} />
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{item.name}</Card.Title>
                  <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
        </Carousel.Item>     
        ))}
        </Carousel>
        </Wrapper>
    </div>
```

I know that to do so I should have 3 `<Carousel.Item>` tags but I can't figure out how to do it with `map`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the goal is to have 3 cards on each slide, it seems that instead of having 3 `<Carousel.Item>`, the desired output should probably be to have each `<Carousel.Item>` containing 3 `<Card>`.

Perhaps try use `reduce` on `recipes` to make an array that groups every 3 recipes to `map` a `<Carousel.Item>` for each group, and then nest another `map` inside to output 3 `<Card>`.

The below example also added a `<div>` to wrap the `<Card>` and place them horizontally. It used bootstrap syntax with assumption that the project also uses bootstrap classes.

But if inline styling is preferred, perhaps change `<div className="d-flex justify-content-center">` to `<div style={{display:"flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>`.

Live demo of the example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fizhve?file=src/App.js)

A very basic example could be:

```
// Helper function to group every 3 recipe to a new array
const reduceRecipes = (acc, cur, index) => {
  const groupIndex = Math.floor(index / 3);
  if (!acc[groupIndex]) acc[groupIndex] = [];
  acc[groupIndex].push(cur);
  console.log(acc);
  return acc;
};

return (
  <div>
    <Wrapper>
      <h3>Breakfast Recipes</h3>
      <Carousel>
        {recipes.reduce(reduceRecipes, []).map((item, index) => (
          <Carousel.Item key={index}>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
              {item.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <Card key={index} style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.photo_location} />
                    <Card.Body>
                      <Card.Title>{item.name}</Card.Title>
                      <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                    </Card.Body>
                  </Card>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </Carousel.Item>
        ))}
      </Carousel>
    </Wrapper>
  </div>
);
```

Some further custom styles should probably be added to make this work better, but hope that this still helps.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I meant yes, but now the cards are stacked vertically on top of each other.. is there a way to make them horizontally?

Comment: @Abdelrhmann02 It seems that there could be another `<div>` to contain and layout the `Card` to fix this. I was just making a live demo about this, please check the updated answer and hopefully it would help.